# Pandas: Convert dictionary to dataframe where keys and values are the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like so:

```
d = {'3a0fe308-b78d-4080-a68b-84fdcbf5411e': 'SUCCEEDED-HALL-IC_GBI', '7c975c26-f9fc-4579-822d-a1042b82cb17': 'SUCCEEDED-AEN-IC_GBI', '9ff20206-a841-4dbf-a736-a35fcec604f3': 'SUCCEEDED-ESP2-IC_GBI'}
```

I would like to convert my dictionary into something like this to make a dataframe where I put all the keys and values in a separate list.

```
d = {'key': ['3a0fe308-b78d-4080-a68b-84fdcbf5411e', '7c975c26-f9fc-4579-822d-a1042b82cb17', '9ff20206-a841-4dbf-a736-a35fcec604f3'],
     'value': ['SUCCEEDED-HALL-IC_GBI', 'SUCCEEDED-AEN-IC_GBI', 'SUCCEEDED-ESP2-IC_GBI']
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `pandas`, try:

```
pd.Series(d).reset_index(name='value').to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'index': ['3a0fe308-b78d-4080-a68b-84fdcbf5411e',
  '7c975c26-f9fc-4579-822d-a1042b82cb17',
  '9ff20206-a841-4dbf-a736-a35fcec604f3'],
 'value': ['SUCCEEDED-HALL-IC_GBI',
  'SUCCEEDED-AEN-IC_GBI',
  'SUCCEEDED-ESP2-IC_GBI']}
```

---

Pure python:

```
{'key':list(d.keys()), 'value': list(d.values())}
```

output:

```
{'key': ['3a0fe308-b78d-4080-a68b-84fdcbf5411e',
  '7c975c26-f9fc-4579-822d-a1042b82cb17',
  '9ff20206-a841-4dbf-a736-a35fcec604f3'],
 'value': ['SUCCEEDED-HALL-IC_GBI',
  'SUCCEEDED-AEN-IC_GBI',
  'SUCCEEDED-ESP2-IC_GBI']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'3a0fe308-b78d-4080-a68b-84fdcbf5411e': 'SUCCEEDED-HALL-IC_GBI',
     '7c975c26-f9fc-4579-822d-a1042b82cb17': 'SUCCEEDED-AEN-IC_GBI',
     '9ff20206-a841-4dbf-a736-a35fcec604f3': 'SUCCEEDED-ESP2-IC_GBI'}
table = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['key', 'value'])
```

If you just want to rearrange your Dictionary you could do this:

```
d2 = {'key': list(d.keys()), 'value': list(d.values())}
```

Comment: This use of `items()` to pass in keys and values as individual columns was just what I was looking for. Not obvious; very clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dataframe zipping the key/value lists with [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(d.keys(),d.values())), columns=['key','value'])
```